# Batch Script | Flash the screen while a command is running

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, vlc

I've created a batch script to call VLC to record. Whilst VLC is recording I want the commmand prompt screen to flash a red and black back ground as a visual indicator that recording is happening.

This is my string to run VLC:

```
vlc screen:// --qt-start-minimized :screen-fps=30 :run-time=300 :quiet :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb072}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="C:\Users\danbradshaw\Desktop\screencast.mp4"} vlc://quit
```

This is how I'm getting the background to cycle colours:

```
:S 
color 40
color 04
goto S
```

As the VLC string stops the runner until VLC is quit I can't place the colour cycle code after. But as the colour cycle code is a loop it stops the VLC string from executing if placed before.

What should I do to get them to run together?

Comment: You can use `START` to start things asynchronously. But there is no way for the two processes to know when the other one has finished unless you want to use a convoluted file drop semaphore process

Comment: Rereading whta you want, it might be as simple as using `START vlc....` instead of `vlc....`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks, that got it working for me!

Comment: It would be great if you could document your solution in an answer and accept it. There's nothing more frustrating than searching for your issue, finding it, then seeing "I got it working" with no explanation.

Comment: I suggest you to change the question title to: "Flash the screen while a command is running". It is more descriptive of your particular requirement.

Comment: @Aacini Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I'll post my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with the suggestions above. Here is my final batch script:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
cd /d C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC
start vlc screen:// --qt-start-minimized :screen-fps=30 :run-time=300 :quiet :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb072}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="C:\Users\danbradshaw\Desktop\screencast.mp4"} vlc://quit
:S 
color 40
timeout 1 >nul
color 04
timeout 1 >nul
goto S
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Mmm... This "solution" is an endless loop... How do you stop the flashing of the screen? When you visually realize that `vlc` command ends and then press Ctrl-C in order to abort the loop?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Aacini, I click the x on the top right of the command prompt window (: The VLC command is the same, I manually stop VLC from recording. The automation is mainly for the initiation of the recording, as it saves me manually configuring the capture details.

Comment: Well, if you manually stop the recording _and_ manually stop the flashing screen, then I don't understand why you need _"a visual indicator that recording is happening"_. Anyway, [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899958/778560) _automatically_ stop the flashing screen when the recording ends, so I could argue that it is a better solution... **`:(`**

Comment: I forget the screen recording is running sometimes. The flashy screen is a good reminder, plus it's looks cooler than just a black cmd window. I tried you're method and it didn't work properly, I didn't troubleshoot it as the other method already worked for me and I was happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@echo off

if "%1" neq "" goto %1

echo Start process
"%~F0" emitter > pipefile.txt | "%~F0" receiver < pipefile.txt
color
echo End process
goto :EOF


:emitter
ping -n 10 -w 500 localhost > CON
echo EOT
exit /B


:receiver
color 40
ping -n 1 localhost > NUL
color 04
ping -n 1 localhost > NUL
set /P "end="
if not defined end goto receiver
exit /B
```

Just replace the `ping -n 10 -w 500 localhost > CON` command I used in my tests by your `vlc screen:// --qt-start-minimized :screen-fps=30 :run-time=300 :quiet :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb072}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="C:\Users\danbradshaw\Desktop\screencast.mp4"} vlc://quit`